# Opening outside files in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

So basically what I'm trying to accomplish is being able to select a file from a displayed list and open that file. Right now I have it set up in a CheckBoxList that displays the .docx, .mov, and .txt files that exist in the selected folder. The problem is I can't get it to open the file. I've seen most people suggesting-

```
Process.Start(filename);
```

But the problem with that is that it requires a specific file name and I'm trying to pull that name from a variable. Any ideas?
Here's my current code -

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string path = @"C:\Users\Haxelle\Documents\Journal";
        List<string> extensions = new List<string> { "DOCX", "MOV", "TXT" };

        string[] files = GetFilesWithExtensions(path, extensions);
        ckbEntry.Items.AddRange(files);
    }

    private string[] GetFilesWithExtensions(string path, List<string> extensions)
    {
        string[] allFilesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        return allFilesInFolder.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.ToUpper().Split('.').Last())).ToArray();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedFiles = ckbEntry.CheckedItems;


    }
```

Trying to open file in btnOpen_Click

Comment: Looks like you have everything you need, and you know how to do it. Just iterate over `selectedFiles` and use `Process.Start(filename);` to open them. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all you are missing is iterating over the selected files names and opening them.  Since the `CheckedItemCollection.Item` is typed as `object`, you will need to cast the items, which can be done using LINQ's `Cast` function.

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedFiles = ckbEntry.CheckedItems;
    foreach (var filename in selectedFiles.Cast<string>()) {
        Process.Start(filename);
    }
}
```